# PRESTAHSOP - add custom input in the address page

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to add a custom input text on the prestashop address list (while doing checkout , on step 3)
is there any hook that can do this job ?
if no, then what is the best method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Addresses page in backoffice, press `Set required fields for this section` and select "other" for example. You can change this text "other" to any other text you need in Translations page.

[image: Addresses page.]

There is no such a hook, but you can add this record to a database during module installation (`install()` function) with a code like that:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('
INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'required_field` (`object_name`, `field_name`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Address', 'other') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT `object_name` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'required_field` 
    WHERE `object_name` = 'Address'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: is it possible to add id via a hook ? as i need to add it via a module